# Algolia Instantsearch with Multiple Indices and Multiple Pagination Widgets

Tags: pagination, algolia, instantsearch.js

I have implemented instantsearch.js with 1 search input and multiple indices, and multiple stats/pagination widgets. Everything seems to be working correctly except for the pagination widgets.

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/flrrrhoffpauir/pen/EEpWre

```
collections.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
        container: '#collections-search-pagination',
        showFirstLast: false,
        labels: {
            next: '>',
            previous: '<',
        },
        cssClasses: {
            root: 'search-pagination'
        }
    })
}

search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
        container: '#stories-search-pagination',
        showFirstLast: false,
        labels: {
            next: '>',
            previous: '<',
        },
        cssClasses: {
            root: 'search-pagination'
        }
    })
}
```

If you search for ‘martin’ and then click the Stories tab, you can see the results and that the pagination is working. If you now click the Collections tab, you can see that the pagination widget has the correct number of pages based on how many results were returned according to the stats widget, but then you click to go to page 2, you are just scrolled to the top of the page and it doesn’t load the page 2 data.

How can I get two or more pagination widgets on the page at once that both work correctly?

This is what I went off of to create the multiple index search, but they don't cover multiple pagination widgets: https://jsfiddle.net/j9nwpz34/49/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `searchFunction` implementation should transfer all the information that needs to be synchronized. For example, in your case you have a pagination widget that you want to sync across instances of InstantSearch, so you want to transfer the pagination property on top of the query parameter.

```js
var search = instantsearch(
{
  /* appId: '',
  apiKey: '', 
  indexName: 'movies',*/
  searchFunction: function(helper) {
    var query = movies.helper.state.query;
    var page = movies.helper.state.page;
    products.helper.setQuery(query);
    products.helper.setPage(page)
    products.helper.search();
    helper.search();
  },
  searchParameters: {
    hitsPerPage: 3
  }
});
```

I've modified the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobylito/yncj06k6/) to match your need. You can learn more about this state by going to the [JS Helper documentation](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/) (internal state management of InstantSearch.js).

Update based on the [jsFiddle provided](https://jsfiddle.net/flrrrhoffpauir/rrf2vbdy/):

The rest of the example still holds. However, one thing to note is that if you make a modification in the helper, it will reset the page. In the provided fiddle, you do such a change in the collections searchFunction. You will always set the query, which will always reset the page to 0. Hence the bug.

Here is a [fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobylito/bsjdch4m/1/)

Comment: Your answer works great, but my question is how can I implement two pagination widgets. One for each index. I've simplified my codepen above into a jsfiddle for readability: https://jsfiddle.net/flrrrhoffpauir/rrf2vbdy/

Again, if you search for "martin" you will see that when clicking "2" on the first pagination widget, the body will scroll to the top but the data does not change for that index. If you click "2" on the second pagination widget, the data for that index does indeed change to page 2, which is what I would like the first pagination widget to do

Comment: So you want to synchronize the pagination back and forth between the two instances of instantsearch?

Comment: No I have 1 instance of instantsearch, 2 indices, and 2 pagination widgets. The pagination widgets need to work with the index they're a widget for. There is no synchronization